# find the number of candidates who still have a chance to win the election

Tags: java, algorithm

Elections are in progress!

Given an array of the numbers of votes given to each of the candidates so far,
 and an integer k the number of voters who haven't cast their vote yet,
  find the number of candidates who still have a chance to win the election.

The winner of the election must secure strictly more votes than any other candidate.
 If two or more candidates receive the same(maximum) number of votes,
  assume there is no winner at all.

Example

For votes = [2, 3, 5, 2] and k = 3, the output should be
**electionsWinners(votes, k) = 2.**

For votes = [1, 3, 3, 1, 1] and k = 0, the output should be
**electionsWinners(votes, k) = 0.**

For votes = [5, 1, 3, 1, 4] and k = 0, the output should be
**electionsWinners(votes, k) = 1.**

```
int electionsWinners(int[] votes, int k) {

int max = votes[0];
int counter = 0;

/* I assumed all the voters who haven't cast their vote,
 votes only 1 candidate */

for(int i = 1; i < votes.length; i++) {
    //getting the candidate who has the highest vote.
    if(votes[i] > max ) {
        max = votes[i];
    }
}

// count the candidates who still have the chance to win.
for(int i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
    if(k != 0){
         if((votes[i] + k) > max) {
        counter++;
        }       
    } else if(k == 0) {
        /* if there is no voters left to vote, 
        and the candidates who has the highest vote will be the winner. 
        and if two or more candidates recieve the same(maximum) number of votes,
        assume there is no winner. */

        // count the no. of candidates who recieve the same(maximum) number of votes.
         if(votes[i] == max) {
        counter++;
             if(counter == 1) {
                 counter = 1;
             } else {
                 counter = 0;
             }
        } 
    }
}
return counter;
}
```

I'm a beginner in programming. trying my best to solve it and that's my code. i just wonder if there is simplified solution for it.

Comment: I recommend posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `if` statements are unnecessarily verbose, e. g. `if (k != 0) A else if (k == 0) B` may be simplified to `if (k != 0) A else B`; `if (counter == 1) counter = 1` is redundant

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your code will work, for `k = 0` and the number of candidates with maximum votes would be equal to `2 * n + 1`, e.g.  `[1, 3, 3, 3, 1]`.
Why? Because of this part:

```
if(votes[i] == max) {
  counter++;
  if(counter == 1) {
     counter = 1;
  } else {
     counter = 0;
  }
}
```

So if you've found 2 candidates with max votes so far, you reset the counter. Then when you find another one, you increase it to `1` and if there's no more candidates with max votes, you return `1` which is clearly incorrect.

The code in the loop should really just be

```
...
} else if (k == 0 && votes[i] == max) {
  counter++;
}
```

And outside of the `for` loop, you do a quick check

```
if (k == 0 && counter > 1)
  counter = 0;
```

Comment: I understand now what is wrong in my code. thanks @radoh

Answer (score 1):

First, your current solution is not correct. In particular, the code

```
if (counter == 1) {
    counter = 1;
} ...
```

is very strange: if counter equals 1, then setting it to 1 has no effect. What happens when `k == 0` is: `counter` switches between 0 and 1, which is not what you want. Try your solution with 3 candidates with the highest number of votes.

You correctly observed that there are two cases: if `k != 0`, you have to check for each candidate whether he/she will win when all remaining voters vote for him/her. If `k == 0` you have to check whether there is a single candidate the highest number of votes. Therefore I would expect your code to look like the following pseudo-code:

```
determine maximum number of votes;

if (k != 0) {
   int counter = the number of candidates who win when all k votes are cast for him/her;
   return counter;
} else {
   int numOfWinners = the number of candidates with a maximum number of votes; 
   return (numOfWinners == 1) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: last `else` may be simplfied: `return (...) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou. Okay. But it's pseudo-code. Since the english instructions require loops, I didn't want to rely on them playing the role of expressions too much.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I developed is the following: I compare the number of possible votes a candidate may get to the maximum of the number of votes of the other candidates.

We could find the maximum number of votes of the other candidates each time we are evaluating the chances of a candidate. But this is very inefficient because the maximum number of votes is the same for all candidates except for the candidate which currently has the maximum number of votes. in this candidate's case, the maximum number of votes of the other candidates is the second highest number of votes. We just need a threshold which is lower than the maximum number of votes, maxActualVotes - 1 is just fine, but I like to be accurate.

There is one more catch: if there are two or more candidates having the highest number of votes in the original array, the maximum number of votes of all the OTHER candidates will be the maximum number of votes of all the candidates for them too.

Considering these, I iterate once through the array of votes and extract the highest and the second highest number of votes and the number of candidates having the highest number of votes.
Then I use the simple solution of establishing the maximum to compare to for each evaluated candidate: the threshold is always the maximum number of votes in the array except for the case when there is only one candidate having the highest number of votes in the array, when the threshold is the second highest number of votes.

The number of candidates still holding chances of winning the elections is incremented each time a candidate having (current number of votes + remaining votes to be casted) larger than the above mention threshold.

This is a Python code snippet:

```
def findThresholds(votes):
    maxActualVotes = 0
    secondMaxActualVotes = 0
    numberOfMaximumActualVotes = 0
    for i in range(len(votes)):
        if votes[i] > maxActualVotes:
            secondMaxActualVotes = maxActualVotes
            maxActualVotes = votes[i]
            numberOfMaximumActualVotes = 1
        elif votes[i] == maxActualVotes:
            numberOfMaximumActualVotes += 1
    return maxActualVotes, numberOfMaximumActualVotes, secondMaxActualVotes

def solution(votes, k):
    maxActualVotes, numberOfMaximumActualVotes, secondMaxActualVotes = findThresholds(votes)

    possibleWinners = 0
    for i in range(len(votes)):
        # find the maximum number of votes to compare to
        if votes[i] == maxActualVotes and numberOfMaximumActualVotes == 1:
            maxToCompareTo = secondMaxActualVotes
        else:
            maxToCompareTo = maxActualVotes
        if votes[i] + k > maxToCompareTo:
            possibleWinners += 1
    return possibleWinners
```

This piece of code correctly handles all the test cases.